# what is the purpose of JFrame setBackground

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When you create `JFrame`  instance, you have `setBackground` method available from this instance. However, regardless  to what color you try to put there, you`ll receive gray background color.

This happens (as i understood), because default `JPanel` instance is automatically  created inside `JFrame` and  lays over it . So, to get  color set, you need to call

```
JFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
```

that actually  calls `setBackground` of default  `JPanel` , that exists  inside `JFrame`.
I also tried to do next :

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame();

//I expect this will set size of JFrame and JPanel 
jf.setSize(300, 500);

//I expect this  to color JFrame background  yellow 
jf.setBackground(Color.yellow);

//I expect this to shrink default JPanel to 100 pixels high, 
//so 400 pixels of JFrame should became visible
jf.getContentPane().setSize(300, 100);

//This will make JPanel red
jf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
```

After this set of code, I am  having solid red square of `JFrame` size , i.e. 300 x 500.
Questions :

1. Why `jf.getContentPane().setSize(300, 100);` does not resize default `JPanel` , revealing `JFrame` background?
2. Why JFrame has `setBackground`  method if anyway you cannot see it and it is covered by default `JPanel` all the time?

Comment: Note that even if the background was set to yellow, it would be set to red just 1 statement later.

Comment: I consider those two as different methods of separate objects: jf.setBackground(Color.yellow); and jf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);  Am i wrong ?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containers]() for information about the structure of a frame. You should not be tying to set the size of any component. That is the job of the layout manager, so even if you set the size of the content pane the layout manager will override the size.

Answer (score 2):

As per the class hierarchies of `JFrame` as shown below:

```
java.lang.Object
    java.awt.Component
        java.awt.Container
            java.awt.Window
                java.awt.Frame
                    javax.swing.JFrame
```

The method [Frame#setBackground()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29) is inherited from [Frame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) and [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) doesn't do override it.

What [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) states:

> The `JFrame` class is slightly incompatible with Frame. Like all other JFC/Swing top-level containers, a `JFrame` contains a **JRootPane** as its only child. The content pane provided by the root pane should, as a rule, contain all the non-menu components displayed by the `JFrame`. This is different from the AWT Frame case.

---

You can override default `setBackground()` of `JFrame` as shown below:

```
@Override
public void setBackground(Color color){
    super.setBackground(color);
    getContentPane().setBackground(color);
}
```

Comment: Just found out , that if i turn off visibility of root content pane, i will see yellow background. Resizing visible root content pane does not reveal part of background though. Am i expecting something proposterous?

Comment: yes its covered by content pane as documented. For component `setSize()` method works based in Layout manager.