# JButton position not functioning

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, null-layout-manager

I'm new to java but know the basics of swing and a majority of the libraries and I was wondering why this practice program I recently made is not positioning a JButton at the right coordinates. I'm stumped. Here is the source code.

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class TitleScreen extends JFrame
{
JFrame window = new JFrame();
JPanel screen = new JPanel();
JButton start = new JButton("Play Game");
JButton end = new JButton("Quit Game");
ImageIcon thing = new ImageIcon("lol.png");
Image pic = thing.getImage();

public TitleScreen()
{
 window.setTitle("Test");
 window.setSize(500,500);
 window.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
 window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 window.setResizable(false);
 window.setVisible(true);
}

public void canvas()
{
screen.setLayout(null);
window.add(screen);
start.setBounds(250,250,100,50);   
screen.add(start);  
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
TitleScreen TitleScreen = new TitleScreen();    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you didn't call the `canvas` method that is why it is not showing.

**solution:**

```
 public TitleScreen()

{
 window.setTitle("Test");
 window.setSize(500,500);
 window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 screen.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
 window.setVisible(true);
 canvas();
}
```

Comment: Also why is that window.setBackground is not making the screen blue. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2451511 dont set the frames background instead set it to your jpanel. editted see above

Comment: wrong to change code lines ordering because you set canvas(); to alredy visible window.setVisible(true);

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes maybe wokrs in this case, but is about basics mistake, for more info to see code in answer by Braj

Answer (score 2):

#### Some points:

- Don't use `null` layout instead use a proper layout that suits as per your need

  It's worth reading about [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)
- Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

  Read more

  - [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
  - [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)
- Always call `JFrame#setVisible(true)` in the end after adding all the component.
- Read more [what is the purpose of JFrame setBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213483/what-is-the-purpose-of-jframe-setbackground?answertab=votes#tab-top)

---

It should be like this:

```
public void canvas() {
    screen.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    screen.add(start);
    window.add(screen);             
}

public TitleScreen() {
    ...
    canvas();
    window.setVisible(true); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TitleScreen TitleScreen = new TitleScreen();
        }
    });
}
```